# resources in site definition

Tags: site-definition, resource-files

I have a problem with resources in my site definition. I have 2 languages dutch (1043) and english (1033). In my site definition i'm using a feature which has a site column. This site column has displayname which is based on a resource.

I also have a contenttype where this column is in but with another displayname which comes from a resource. This contenttype I'm using in a custom list.

If I create the site from the site definition, I get a wrong displayname in my list. But the strange thing is that when I delete the list, and re-activate my feature, the displayname is correct.

Here some code to clarify my problem. This is my site column:

```
  <Field Type="Number" 
     DisplayName="$Resources:dmx.autonumbering,FieldDisplayName" 
     Required="FALSE" 
     ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
     ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
     EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" 
     Indexed="TRUE" 
     Group="Datamex Automatisering" 
     ID="{b9d9771e-72ba-411f-b259-1776ddd99526}"
     StaticName="DMXAutoNumber" 
     Name="DMXAutoNumber" 
     Overwrite="TRUE" 
     Sealed="FALSE"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
```

I'm using this site column in my contenttype with a resource in my displayname

```
   <ContentType ID="0x01010044e1b4de787b4b7d9ae26b770906f77f0092a56f1213a94172b4c30d7dd97b04ea0068d247cd7b394362b3dc725f72d020ef"
           Name="$Resources:Yucatan.ContentTypes,Certificate;"
           Group="$Resources:Yucatan.ContentTypes,ContentTypeGroup;"
           Description="$Resources:Yucatan.ContentTypes,CertificateDescription;"              
           Inherits="TRUE"
           Version="0">
     <FieldRefs>
       <FieldRef ID="{b9d9771e-72ba-411f-b259-1776ddd99526}" Name="DMXAutoNumber" DisplayName="$Resources:Yucatan.Fields,CertificateNumber;" />
     </FieldRefs>
   </ContentType>
```

In my custom list I reference this contenttype, and using these fields in my view:

```
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
      <FieldRef Name="Title" />
      <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" />
      <FieldRef Name="AdministrationNumber" />
      <FieldRef Name="DMXAutoNumber" />
      <FieldRef Name="Pages" />
      <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
    </ViewFields>
```

In the of the sitecolumn the text is "AutoNumber", in the resource of the contenttype the text is "Certificate".

If I activate the feature myself the text is "Certificate" which is correct. If I create a site with my site definition (which uses the same feature to create the libraries) the text is "AutoNumber" which is incorrect.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I have some simular strange behavior when i was creating site by using powershell, but reactivate feature by hands. The solve was to restart powershell before deploying.

Comment: What do you mean by Wrong Name? it is taken from a wrong resource file?

Comment: With wrong name I mean the name of the site column, not the name in the contenttype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution. Deleting the Overwrite="TRUE" from the field definition resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating this using code or markup?

If you coded this, use `.TitleResource` (and `.DescriptionResource` if needed) instead of `.Title` to set the title properly for all desired languages.

`.Title` will only get you the title for the current language running the sitecreation process, and the `.Title` property doesn't work properly with the quicknav on multilingual sites either.

Comment: I'm creating the sitecolumn, contenttype and list using markup